# Getting and echo element including content by ID using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get an element from external page (div tag including some content) by its ID and print it to another page on a site.  I am trying to use the code below however getting tag errors which I have in the including element (figcaption, figure). Is there anyway to include only a single div by its ID from another page?

PHP

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/includes/example.html');

$example = $doc->getElementById('test');

echo $example->nodeValue;

?>
```

HTML

```
<div id="test">
    <figure>
        <img src="img1.jpg" alt="img" />
        <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/server-side-html-handling-using-phpquery/
or
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
etc.

Comment: useful links, will take a look definitely, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOMDocument output errors on HTML5 even if there are not error, due to impossibility of DTD check.

To avoid this, simply change your code in this way:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors( True );
$doc->loadHTMLFile( '$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/includes/example.html' );
```

Anyway — even if some errors are displayed — your code load correctly HTML document, but you can't display the `<div>` because you use a wrong syntax: change `echo $example->nodeValue`
with:

```
echo $doc->saveHTML( $example );
```

The right syntax to print DOM HTML is `DOMDocument->saveHTML()`, or — if you want print only part of document — `DOMDocument->saveHTML( DOMElement )`.

Also note that DOMDocument is designed to not try to preserve formatting from the original document, so you probably don't obtain this:

```
<div id="test">
    <figure>
        <img src="img1.jpg" alt="img" />
        <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

but this:

```
<div id="test">
    <figure><img src="img1.jpg" alt="img"><figcaption></figcaption></figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great solution. Actually it worked with the direct file link and same HTML formatting. The libxml_use_internal_errors( True ) fixed error and echo $doc->saveHTML( $example ); showed all the content. Maybe this is because PHP7 I have? :)

Comment: “This” what? The errors? No, errors on HTML5 are displayed also on previous version.

Comment: I mean it works with the link to file I had, I did not change to absolute one as you suggested, and second thing is that I did not change html formatting, it remained as it was.

Comment: Aha sorry, I didn't get you right about the HTML :)

Comment: Sorry me too! My link was not a suggestion: it's only my testing link! I forget to change it in the answer... I will update it. Your link is totally valid even in older php

Comment: Great then! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are currenlt only `echo`-ing node value, which will be text. Since you have no text in `#test`, nothing will output.

You have to print it as HTML:

```
echo $doc->saveHTML($example);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but I was still having errors. Next question solved the issues.